# Why is $\lambda$-sufficiency necessary for No-Go Theorems?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, bells-inequality, foundations

In a talk given by Spekkens ([Why I Am Not a Psi-ontologist](https://pirsa.org/12050021)) at 4:00 he talks about an assumption called $\lambda$-sufficiency which is part of any no-go theorem of quantum mechanics. It is described as stating "Once an ontic state is specified, its response to experimental probes is often assumed to be independent of the quantum state, since the latter is just a statistical mixture of the former" in a paper by Lin ([Conspiracy in ontological models – λ-sufficiency and measurement contextuality](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2010.10688.pdf)). \begin{equation}
p(k \mid M, P, \lambda)=p(k \mid M, \lambda)
\end{equation} ($k$ is the outcome, $M$ the measurement, $P$ the preparation and $\lambda$ the ontic state). Why is this a necessary assumptions e.g. for the PBR theorem or Bell's theorem? What is the problem if we do not subscribe to this assumption?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because there has not been any answers, maybe someone who stumbles across this in the future may find this helpful. After some time thinking about it and researching, this is the best explanation i can come up with:

All No-Go theorems, but especially PBR "depend" on the ontological model framework by Spekkens, which is based on an operationalist interpretation of quantum mechanics (as probably most interpretations do). An operationalist interpretation entails that \begin{equation} p(k | M, P) = \int\limits_\Lambda d \lambda \, p(k |\lambda,M) p(\lambda | P)  \overset{!}{=} \operatorname{tr}\left(\rho E_k\right).\end{equation} For this to be the case, we have to assume both \begin{align}
p(\lambda \mid M, P)&=p(\lambda \mid P)\\
p(k \mid M, P, \lambda)&=p(k \mid M, \lambda)
\end{align} so that we can use the law of total probability to derive the left side of the upper equation. Because the first of these assumptions seems trivial, Spekkens probably only talks about the second one.